# tracking social media shares,likes,hashtags through a website

Tags: php, social-networking, event-tracking

i wanted to know if the following concept is possible.
i am creating a website using PHP which tracks multiple users posts (hashtags,comments,likes) on  various social media such as facebook,twitter and instagram.

The user needs to do registration on my website and whenever he puts a post/comments with a specific hashtag on fb,tw or instagram, my website tracks it and assigns some points to that user on my website.

i have no clue if it is even possible. It would be nice if someone could help. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sample that i think will help you with your needs

For shares on twitter

use this callback url from twitter via API

https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.yourdomain.com

Out put will be like this

```
{
    "count": 22,
    "url": "http://www.yourdomain.com/"
}
```

for Facebook
    https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.yourdomain.com

```
{
    "id": "http://www.yourdomain.com",
    "shares": 60
}
```

Comments, likes and share count

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.yourdomain.com&format=json

```
[{
     "url": "http://www.yourdomain.com",
     "normalized_url": "http://www.yourdomain.com/",
     "share_count": 11,
     "like_count": 23,
     "comment_count": 26,
     "total_count": 60,
     "click_count": 0,
     "comments_fbid": 10150451628634400,
     "commentsbox_count": 0
}]
```

for more info please check this link
https://www.madebymagnitude.com/blog/getting-your-social-share-counts-with-php/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15653262)

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited my answer i hope its more of a proper answer now.